# How do you push/launch a rigidbody2d horizontally that already has a set velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

**How do you launch yourself horizontally with a rigidbody2d if it already has a set velocity?**

For instance, you might want to do a knockback of some sorts, or in my instance, a trampoline, that will require the player to move horizontally and vertically (based on the rotation on the trampoline it self). I've tried rigidbody2d.AddForce() but problem is that the player movement script sets the players horizontal movement to 0 constantly, and so when you rotate the trampoline horizontally, the player just isn't launched.

Here is an example of my rigidbody2d movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 move;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField] float speed;


    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update() {
        float inputH = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        move = new Vector2(inputH, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move.x * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

As we can see the velocity is constantly getting set to 0 as you're not inputting any movement. So how do I make a script that can launch the player in every direction?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** you want to make sure that both the player and the object that you're colliding with have the appropriate colliders. So the player in this instance will have a rigidbody2d and a collider (is trigger set to TRUE), and the object will have a collider (no need for rigidbody2d or is trigger here).

Now that everything is setup, we want to place a script in the object that will launch the player. This script is called Trampoline in my example and will contain this code:

```
public class Trampoline: MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        LaunchObject(collision.gameObject);
    }

    void LaunchObject(GameObject _object) {
         if(_object.CompareTag("Player")) {
             // Change the temporary move so that the player moves a certain vector.
             InputHandler _playerInput = _object.GetComponent<InputHandler>();
            _playerInput.temporaryMove = transform.up * trampolineForce;
        }
    }
}
```

This will launch the player by using velocity instead of AddForce. This will allow the player to replace the currently set velocity of 0, to this temporary one called "temporaryMove". This variable will replace the velocity.x in the player movement script.

**Now lets also create a script called "InputHandler"** and place it on the player object (same place as where the movement for the player is placed). The InputHandler will have this code in it:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour {
     public Vector2 temporaryMove {get;set;} 
}
```

This is just to split up the code so that the scripts are less reliable on each other, and can instead be replaced by a public variable in the PlayerScript.

Now we also want the player movement script from before to get a couple of changes so that it can replace it's current velocity to a temporary one until you touch the ground. In this case we also want the player to be able to counteract the force while in the air. This will now be the new player movement script:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector2 move;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    InputHandler _input;

    [SerializeField] float movementSpeed;


    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _input = GetComponent<InputHandler>();
    }

    void Update() {
        HorizontalMovement();
        ForcedMovement();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2((_input.temporaryMove.x != 0 ? _input.temporaryMove.x : (_input.move.x * movementSpeed)), _input.temporaryMove.y != 0 ? _input.temporaryMove.y : rb.velocity.y);

    }

    private void HorizontalMovement() {
        float inputH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        move = new Vector2(inputH, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private void ForcedMovement() {
        //* This will force player movement until they touch ground, or counteract the forced movement by moving
        //* This is intended for Trampoline for instance

        //If there isn't any movement, return
        if(_input.temporaryMove.magnitude == 0) return;
   

        float moveInputAmpfliy = 1.5f; //How much the player can impact the mid air movement
        knockbackTimer -= Time.deltaTime; // Time before it can detect ground again (Allowing     player to use trampoline on ground)

        //Counteract horizontal movement
        //Counteract vertical movement
        _input.temporaryMove += new Vector2(
            (_input.temporaryMove.x != 0 ? move.x * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed * moveInputAmpfliy : 0),
            (_input.temporaryMove.y != 0 ? Physics2D.gravity.y * rb.gravityScale * Time.deltaTime : 0)
        );


        //Reset if ground is touched
        if(_input.isGrounded && knockbackTimer <= 0) {
            knockbackTimer = 0.5f;
            _input.temporaryMove = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

*Heads up, this code uses a lot of the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), and so if you don't know what it is or how to use it, I would recommend reading it if you want to understand the script.*

But essentially if there is any magnitude to the _input.temopraryMove, then the player will instead have their velocity replace by that variable (_input.temopraryMove) until they touch the ground. The player can also counteract the movement mid air by moving, so that they can launch themselves further if they in the same direction as the launch pad, or less so if they move in the opposite direction.

*If you don't want them to move mid-air, then remove all instances of  "moveInputAmplify".*

And there we go. Now we can launch or player in the direction of the rotation of the trampoline! Hope this helped!